# wine can only find libs with sudo

Tags: linux, wine

I have installed wine recently, but I can only run programs with wine using sudo.

```
/opt/wine-devel/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It gives this error, I checked to see if wine was trying find the libs in the wrong dir, but isn't the case since if I use:

```
sudo wine program.exe
```

it runs correctly.

Comment: Maybe the lib wine files only have read acces with root privilige since they are no standard libs and most likely run OS stuff they need root acces to work

Comment: hey @justaguy I tried give ``chmod 777``, but doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem just doing a `chown <user> /opt/wine-<branch>`. But doesn't do it after has used the wine with sudo and installing some packages or programs, they will be yet unreachable locked by the permissions, use `chown` just after download wine from the winehq page.

Comment: It is a dangerous workaround. The binary files inside /opt/wine-<branch> can be changed by attackers. The owner should be restored after fixing the bug:
sudo chown root /opt/wine-<branch>

Comment: For me, only the following command is helpful: sudo chown -R <user> /opt/wine<branch>. To restore the previous state: sudo chown -R root /opt/wine<branch>

Answer (score -1):

```
winecfg

/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

wine-5.0.1 *
Mate 1.24.0 *
Linux Mint-20 *
Kernel 5.4.0-40

After changing to Mint 19 wine didn't work any longer. What shall I do?

Comment: I think your post shopuld be put in the comments as it is not an answer to the question from Kameda